# How do I upload this canvas png as an NFT?

Tags: react, message, html, css

I'm trying to create a basic message sender that allows you to type a message and send it to any SOL address. I know HTML & CSS but new to react and know little basic js.

This was built using `npx create-solana-dapp` and the page is just a duplicate of the `basics` page. Thanks for your help!

[image]

After the user pastes the address & types the message it should upload as an NFT an send to the recipients SOL address.

Comment: Are you looking for an entire code or you want us to point you to a resource/reference you can use?

Comment: Hi @KristianQuirapas , would love to learn some resources!  Want to learn as much as I can

Answer (score 1):

I love that, William! You can check this page out. I compiled the resources you can use to learn for all levels. Start from the beginner level first because it's important you go through the fundamentals first before you level up to actual dapp creation.

https://solana-philippines.github.io/#/resources